# Clean vertical list

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

So, i have a list of of Urls here and i want to print them separately.

```
['https://gogoanime.gg/aware-meisaku-kun-episode-222', 'https://gogoanime.gg/motto-majime-ni-fumajime-kaiketsu-zorori-3rd-season-episode-10', 'https://gogoanime.gg/yugioh-go-rush-episode-18', 'https://gogoanime.gg/tokyo-mew-mew-new-episode-5', 'https://gogoanime.gg/jashin-chan-dropkick-x-episode-5']
```

i want the output like this. how can get this

```
https://gogoanime.gg/aware-meisaku-kun-episode-222
https://gogoanime.gg/motto-majime-ni-fumajime-kaiketsu-zorori-3rd-season-episode-10
https://gogoanime.gg/yugioh-go-rush-episode-18 
https://gogoanime.gg/tokyo-mew-mew-new-episode-5
https://gogoanime.gg/jashin-chan-dropkick-x-episode-5
```

here's the code

```
from operator import index
import re
from urllib import response
from venv import create
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from numpy import append
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from gogo import links

iframe_url = links
New_links = (','.join(links))
transformed_string=re.sub(",","",new_links)
```

Comment: `for l in links: print(l)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print `New_links` after following op:

```
New_links = '\n'.join(links)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about unpacking the list?

```
print(*links, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple for loop iterating through your list you can print

```
for url in links:
    print(url)
```